# Designing REST API for Different Consumers

Tags: rest, api-design

I have an application API that is used In two scenarios:

1. My frontend application uses it to interact with the server
2. A client is using it for development of CLI tool so there is an open documentation of the API.

At start all of the endpoints were kind of generic so they have been used in both scenarios, but as my application grows i have a need to :

- create special endpoints for my frontend application for optimization, for example an endpoint to some statistics screen
- Change some of the basic API results structures that are not backward compatible and can break the Clients
  usage.

What is the best practice to design an API to meet these needs? 
How is should be design correctly so it will be adjusted
to the frontend needs and on the other side will be robust enough to not break the Client's applications?
frontend specific endpoints along with General ones?

Comment: 1. sometimes you need specialized endpoints. it's not ideal, but whatever, it happens in the real world. 2. API versioning solves backwards compatibility issues.  You should tell the client though they need to update to new version within a timeframe

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best practice to design an API to meet these needs?

This highly depends on your scenario. Is your API going to be used internally only or will it be made publicly available to an unknown number of developers and integrators? What is the expected lifetime of the API? Will it evolve?

> How is should be design correctly so it will be adjusted to the frontend needs and on the other side will be robust enough to not break the Client's applications?

I recommend to commit to API contracts and use a specification for these contracts. I prefer the [OpenAPI specification](http://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.2) as it will come with a lof of benefits. Make sure you invest a lot of time and team effort (product owner, project managers, backend & frontend devs) to develop the contract in several iterations. After each iteration test the specification by mocking the API and clients before turning over to to implement your frontend app or cli client.

> frontend specific endpoints along with General ones?

I would not do that, but I do not know you context. What does a frontend specific endpoint mean? If it means that as of today the endpoint should be only used by the frontend application but is of no use for the current cli client than I think it is just a matter of perspective. Make it a general endpoint and just use it by the frontend app. If it somewhat provides sensitive information that should be access only by the frontend you need to think about authentication and authorization. I recommend implementing [Oauth2](https://oauth.net/2/) for that.

> create special endpoints for my frontend application for optimization, for example an endpoint to some statistics screenfrontend specific endpoints along with General ones?

I would suggest to implement all endpoints in your API and use OAuth2 as authentication. Use the scopes of the OAuth approach to manage authorization and access to different endpoints for each client (frontend app, cli).

You wrote you need to:

> Change some of the basic API results structures that are not backward compatible and can break the Clients usage.

Try to avoid making breaking changes to your API. If it is used internally only you may be in control of the different clients accessing the API but even than the risk of breaking a client is high.

If you need to change existing behaviour you should think about [API versioning](https://nordicapis.com/introduction-to-api-versioning-best-practices/) or [API evolution](https://apisyouwonthate.com/blog/api-evolution-for-rest-http-apis), which is a [controversly discussed topic with a lot of different opinions and practices](https://apisyouwonthate.com/blog/api-versioning-has-no-right-way).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. When I wrote about frontend "specific" endpoint i meant that one of my dashboard screens has to show a lot of summarized data by different categories. When I used the regular endpoints i had very bad performance because so i had to create some performance - optimized endpoint for that screen, that as you understand will be used only in this screen (very specific). 
In this way - endpoints are created for specific consumer

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best practice to design an API to meet these needs?

Design your resource representations so that they are forward and backwards compatible by design.  Fundamentally, they are *messages*, so treat them that way; new optional fields with reasonable defaults can be added to the messages, but the semantics of a message element should never change.

If you dig through the old XML literature, you'll find references to ideas like `Must Ignore` and `Must Forward` -- those are the sorts of princples that also apply to the representations of long lived resources.

Create new resources  when the existing resources cannot be conveniently extended to cover your new use case.